# Array randomly parsed as null, and I have no idea why

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So here's the JSON file I'm trying to parse usin JSON.Net

```
{
  "SystemsInGal": [
    {
      "Name": "HIP 16607",
      "xPos": 0,
      "yPos": 0,
      "StationsInSys": [
        {
          "Name": "Thome Gateway",
          "SystemName": "HIP 16607",
          "DistanceFromStar": 2573,
          "PricePerFuel": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Frenis",
      "xPos": 10,
      "yPos": 10,
      "StationsInSys": [
        {
          "Name": "Parsons City",
          "SystemName": "Frenis",
          "DistanceFromStar": 32,
          "PricePerFuel": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is here

```
"StationsInSys": [
        {
          "Name": "Parsons City",
          "SystemName": "Frenis",
          "DistanceFromStar": 32,
          "PricePerFuel": 20
        }
      ]
```

When parsed by JSON.NET, it simply gives this array the value of null, which certainly isn't what I'm after. The first StationsInSys array is parsed correctly, however the second one isn't. People have checked, and said they couldn't find any differences I haven't corrected. JSONlint claims this file is valid JSON. My only other guess is that there is a problem with JSON.NEt itself, but I would assume this isn't the case

EDIT: Here's how I have my classes setup

```
public class Galaxy
    {
        public SolarSystem[] SystemsInGal { get; set; }
        public Player player { get; set; }
    }

public class Station
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SystemName { get; set; }
        public int DistanceFromStar { get; set; }
        public int PricePerFuel { get; set; }
        //TODO Add trade data here
    }

public class SolarSystem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int xPos { get; set; }
        public int yPos { get; set; }
        public Station[] StationsInSys { get; set; }
    }
```

`Galaxy gal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Galaxy>(jsonText);`

I hope that helps

Comment: Plz share you C#. Are you reading `SystemsInGal` as JArray?

Comment: Post the code statements that you are using to parse the data.

Comment: Without the C# code, it's hard to know what you're trying in JSON.NET to parse the content. Are you using a class, for instance. (You can easily generate some code from your JSON using https://app.quicktype.io).

Comment: Right, so turns out I was a complete and total idiot. The file I was editing was a copy of the file that my unit test was using. So as a result, my edits were not taking effect. Sorry for posting this. I really was frustrated at the time as nothing was working, and Stack Overflow is always my last resort. I'm gonna leave two things I've learned from this. - Make sure you're code has no typos - If you cannot find a solution STOP, and come back to it later. I found the solution less than five minutes after I came back to it

Answer (score 1):

I tried using Visual Studio 2017's `Edit | Paste Special | Paste JSON as classes` feature to create classes for this. That appeared to work. (I didn't bother to correct the casing of the generated class names.)

Here's the resulting code - how does it differ from yours?

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Systemsingal[] SystemsInGal { get; set; }
    }

    public class Systemsingal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int xPos { get; set; }
        public int yPos { get; set; }
        public Stationsinsy[] StationsInSys { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stationsinsy
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SystemName { get; set; }
        public int DistanceFromStar { get; set; }
        public int PricePerFuel { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string data =
                @"{
  ""SystemsInGal"": [
    {
      ""Name"": ""HIP 16607"",
      ""xPos"": 0,
      ""yPos"": 0,
      ""StationsInSys"": [
        {
          ""Name"": ""Thome Gateway"",
          ""SystemName"": ""HIP 16607"",
          ""DistanceFromStar"": 2573,
          ""PricePerFuel"": 10
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      ""Name"": ""Frenis"",
      ""xPos"": 10,
      ""yPos"": 10,
      ""StationsInSys"": [
        {
          ""Name"": ""Parsons City"",
          ""SystemName"": ""Frenis"",
          ""DistanceFromStar"": 32,
          ""PricePerFuel"": 20
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}";
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(data);

            Console.WriteLine(result.SystemsInGal.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey cool, I didn't know you could do that in visual studio. I've just done it manually. My class is missing {get; set;}. I assumed this wasn't an issue, since it's worked with everything else, however on second thought that might be causing the issue. I'll change my code now

EDIT: It didn't :(

Comment: VS can generate classes, as can http://json2csharp.com/ or https://app.quicktype.io/. Sometimes, depending on the JSON, one may give you a little bit better class structure.